# PHPUnit, superglobal vars. How to setup test such that $_SERVER and $_GET are properly set?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am writing some PHP code to parse incoming URLs. It relies heavily on PHP globals such as `$_SERVER` and `$_GET`. I am thinking of manually setting these up in PHPUnit unit test `setUp()` function. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 13):

An idea would be to wrap $_SERVER and $_GET into classes instead of accessing them directly, so that you do not have to rely on them altogether. You see this approach frequently in the common frameworks. This way you can stub or mock the request easily without having to setup the state of the superglobals.

An example of such a class would be here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73515/http-request-response-class

Comment: Could you give an example of how to setup the state of superglobals without a wrapper? (Even though it's smelly)

Comment: @JayIsTooCommon you just set them in your test, e.g. $_SERVER["foo"] = 42 if I recall correctly. Can do so in the actual test method or in setup() or in setupbeforeclass() (if that still exists nowadays)

Comment: Ah ok, I must be doing something else wrong then. Thanks :)

Comment: I know this thread is a bit old, but I have a question: even if you wrap the global variables $_SERVER, $_GET, etc... in a class, you still have to test the class which uses these variables and returns data from them. Could you provide an example of the wrapping class?

Comment: @tonix added added a link to an example class. With that you'd simply do new `Request($_GET, $_POST, …)` in production and in your test you'd use `new Request([], [], …)` instead, e.g. you'd pass in arrays that contain what your $_GET, $_POST, etc are expected to hold.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at it!